# MacBook Pro Retina 15" (Mid-2015) New battery has weird metering

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

New battery installed.
Charges up to 100%, runs down to 50% then suddenly instantly drops to 7% and stays there for about 2 hours. Battery seems to continue to work but metering is wrong. Tried all the usual tricks (Battery conditioning, SMC, PRAM, NVRAM, Reboot, Reinstall MacOS...etc) with no solution in sight.
Any ideas? Just a crappy battery?
Apple asked for $700USD for a replacement so I bought an aftermarket one for 1/10th of the asking price.

Comment: You've already performed the steps I would advise to take and you've (probably) already read thru the several dozen answer already given on this site for battery issues.  Part of the reason Apple charges so much is quality control.  Based on what you've provided, I'd say you have a bad battery.  Is it possible to get it replaced, maybe under warranty?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have already tried all the things that can be recommended in your case. I would assume your battery is faulty.

For anyone else with this model reading the thread: if you do have a Mid 2015 MacBook Pro your battery might be eligible for free replacement unter a quality program: https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall

You could check for the QP as well Vaultnaemsae, but chances are Apple is going to decline coverage as you already performed unauthorized service on the machine (and your Apple battery is no longer a threat as you took it out, which would be the whole point of Apple replacing it free of charge.)